# Can I set a static member in a spring bean class which depends on `@DependsOn`?

Tags: java, spring

As the title
`private static int someConfig = Config.getInstance().getSomeConfig("some");`
and the config needs initialized before being used.
Can I use this when the class `@DependsOn` the Config(Config needs initialized before using)

Comment: It depends. Usually it is a bad practice to use static class/member in beans.

Comment: The assignment to `someConfig` will be made when the class which contains it is loaded. Spring will have no effect on that. Why don't you use Spring instead of static members?